# Buffer video frames and display on PyQt5 GUI with multiprocessing: window never displays an image

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing

My project involves capturing frames from a camera, making inferences on these frames using a trained DL model, and displaying the image with inference information on a GUI. In order to address the delays of inference, I have implemented a frame buffer which stores only the most recent frame captured from the camera which runs in a separate process. The consumer process reads the most recent stored frame, displays the frame on the UI, and meanwhile does its processing and inference on the image. After the processing and inference is done, the consumer will be ready and should retrieve the next frame from the buffer. The frame buffer is implemented as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import cv2
import numpy as np

class FrameBuffer():

    def __init__(self, frame_dim, shared_mem_lock, init_event, exit_event):
        self.camera = None
        self.sh_mem_name = 'Shared_Mem_Name'
        self.shared_lock = shared_mem_lock
        self.init_event = init_event
        self.exit_event = exit_event

        # Create dummy array of specified size
        dummy_arr = np.empty(shape=tuple(self.frame_dim), dtype=np.uint8)
        # Create shared_memory buffer to store frames
        self.sh_mem_buff = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=self.sh_mem_name, create=True, size=dummy_arr.nbytes)
        # Attach numpy array to shared_memory buffer
        self.stored_frames = np.ndarray(dummy_arr.shape, dtype=dummy_arr.dtype, buffer=self.sh_mem_buff.buf)
        # Initialize shared array with dummy values
        self.stored_frames[:] = dummy_arr[:]

    def run(self):
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.init_event.wait()
        try:
            while not self.exit_event.is_set():
                ret_val, frame = self.camera.read()
                if not ret_val:
                    print('No frame grabbed')
                    continue
                # Copy captured frame into object attribute backed by shared memory buffer
                with self.shared_lock:    
                    self.stored_frames[:] = frame[:]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            print("PRODUCER: finally block")
            self.sh_mem_buff.close()
            self.sh_mem_buff.unlink()
            self.camera.release()
```

And the main script which implements the consumer and GUI is as follows:

```
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event, Lock, Value
import numpy as np
import cv2
# PyQt imports 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from camera_functions import FrameBuffer

def producer(capture_buffer):
    capture_buffer.run()

def convert_cv2_to_qt(cv_image):
    h, w, ch = cv_image.shape
    bytes_per_line = ch * w
    converted_qimage = QImage(cv_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)
    scaled_qimage = converted_qimage.scaled(w, h, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    return QPixmap.fromImage(scaled_qimage)

def consumer(frame_buffer, init_event, exit_event, buffer_lock, frame_dim, image_qtlabel):
    frame = np.empty(shape=tuple(frame_dim), dtype=np.uint8)
    init_event.wait()
    while not exit_event.is_set():
        with buffer_lock:
            frame[:] = frame_buffer.stored_frames[:]
            
        pixel_map = convert_cv2_to_qt(frame)
        image_qtlabel.setPixmap(pixel_map)
        image_qtlabel.repaint()
        time.sleep(1.5)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initializeUI()
        
    def initializeUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100,100,800,800)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 window")

        # Create a label to display image
        self.image_label = QLabel(self)
        self.image_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Setup GUI layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # Create a central widget
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

def main():
    # Parameters for camera capture and 
    frame_dim = [512, 640, 3]
    shared_lock = Lock()
    init_event = Event()
    exit_event = Event()
    try: 
        # Create frame buffer object
        capture_buffer = FrameBuffer(n_frames, frame_dim, img_num_value, shared_lock, init_event, exit_event)
    # Start frame capture/buffer process
        capture_process = Process(target=producer, args=(capture_buffer,))
        capture_process.start()
        app = QApplication([])
        window = MainWindow()
        consumer_process = Process(target=consumer, args=[capture_buffer, init_event,
                                                          exit_event, shared_lock,
                                                          frame_dim, window.label])
        consumer_process.start()
        window.show()
        init_event.set()
        app.exec_()

    finally:
        exit_event.set()
        capture_process.join()
        capture_process.close()
        sys.exit()
```

where I simulate the processing and inference time with a sleep function in the consumer.

Unfortunately, my window never displays an image. Both the consumer and producer processes are running fine. I suspect the issue may be some subtlety with how the consumer process is communicating with the user interface process, but I am unsure. I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: you know, you *can* just `self.stored_frames = frame` without the slicing (the lock is a good idea in any case).

Comment: As UI elements cannot be accessed from external threads, they certainly cannot be accessed from external *processes*.